# Uploadify onError

Tags: uploadify, onerror

I am using uploadify to upload pictures on my website. I have a quick question regarding onError function. the situation is, when a user selects an image to upload. lets say the path is c:/documents/mypicture.jpg. and deletes that pictures, so that c:/documents/mypicture.jpg does not exist. and then the upload botton is clicked. How do I deal with this situation. I would like to alert this error but nothing is working. instead a new window opens, which states ERROR #2038 file i/o error.

Please help. Thank you.